# Constraints on cone of semialgebraic set

Tags: real-algebraic-geometry, semialgebraic-geometry

Let $S$ be a (basic) semialgebraic set, for which we know the constraints (i.e. we know the polynomial inequalities and equalities which define the set). Is it necessarily the case that the cone $C = \mathbb{R}^+ S$ is a semialgebraic set, and if so, can one determine  the inequalities and equations which define $C$ (i.e. is there an algorithm to find the constraints)?

edit:

- what if $S$ is a spectrahedron?
- what if $S = \text{conv}(X)$ where $X$ is a real algebraic set?

Comment: Isn't it obvious? I may miss the whole point, but it seems to me that if $S$ lies in $\mathbb R^n=\{x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\}$, defined by $E_j(x)=0$ and $I_j(x)\geq0$, then the subset $C\subset \mathbb R^{n+1}=\{(x,t)\}$ is given by  $t\geq 0$ and $E_j(x/t)=0$ and $I_j(x/t)\geq 0$, constraints which translate directly as polynomial constraints in $(x,t)$ because each $E_j,I_j$  is polynomial and $t\geq 0$.